# Reversed bitmap when creating AVI container

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, stream, avi

I have a list of images in my program, and I am generating an AVI video from them. For that purpose I use avifilewrapper_src library that handles the creation of video. 
The process of creating is:

```
        Bitmap bitmap;
        //load the first image
        bitmap = (Bitmap)imageSequence[0];

        //create a new AVI file
        AviManager aviManager = new AviManager(paths.outputVideo, false);
        //add a new video stream and one frame to the new file
        VideoStream aviStream =
                    aviManager.AddVideoStream(true, (double)nud_picturePerSec.Value, bitmap);

        if(chb_audio.Checked)
            aviManager.AddAudioStream(paths.sampleAudio, 0);


        int count = 0;
        for (int n = 0; n < imageSequence.Count; n++) {
            bitmap = (Bitmap)imageSequence[n];
            aviStream.AddFrame(bitmap);
            bitmap.Dispose();
            count++;
        }

        aviManager.Close();
```

If I keep giving different images, it works fine. If I however, put two similar images, than the video shows second image upside down (left/right side is correct). By two similar images I mean creating second image and copying it from the first one.

I have a feeling that this is somehow related to streams, but I can't find why the images are inverted.

Answer (score 1):

Well I didn't managed to find the cause of that behavior. But fliping it between each use does the correction well.

```
bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);
```